# How to reboot several remote machines via ssh in a single CLI command

Tags: linux, ssh, xargs, reboot

What I want to achieve is to reboot several remote servers without having to log into each individually.
So I fire away the following, hoping it would hop onto server 93, 95 and 97 and reboot each.

```
[root@<home_server> ~]# seq 93 2 97 |xargs -I{} ssh <remoteservernumber_>{} "hostname; reboot"

The authenticity of host '<remoteservernumber_93 (IP.IP.IP.IP)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'remoteservernumber_93 (IP.IP.IP.IP)' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

root@remoteservernumber_93's password:
remoteservernumber_93
Connection to remoteservernumber_93 closed by remote host.
xargs: ssh: exited with status 255; aborting
```

However, what I end up getting is when the first server is rebooted it terminates the connection and it does not hop onto the next server. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can login as root via ssh. Big big ouch. Never ever allow that.

Comment: Absolutely right, you are. I wouldn't, if this was a public network. Luckily this sits so far away from the public domain that I'm okay with this setup for now. But the question still remains, where does my logic fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For want of a better alternative I found the following script works:

```
for i in <server-1> <server-2> ... <server-n> ; do ssh $i "hostname; sudo reboot"; done
```